Question about enabling HSTS in tomcat (8.5) with domain name without www
this is a question about setting HSTS (Strict-Transport_Security) in tomcat. I followed several sources in the web, and enabled in the following in the config/web.xml
     <filter>
            <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
                <param-value>31536000</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
                <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

The setting went well.  When I test the setting with www.example.name (using curl), it returns the following:
>> curl -s -D- https://www.example.com | grep -i Strict
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains

But when I test with example.com (without www), it doesn't show the Strict-Transport-Security in the header.
How can I make this work?
